Divisors of n and n + 1
Suppose $a$ is a proper divisor of $n$ (where $n$ is a positive integer), and $b$ a proper divisor of $n + 1$.
Is there a general criterion (or general property of $n$) which enables one to conclude that $a - b$ cannot be divisible by at least two distinct prime divisors of $n$ (whatever $a$ and $b$ are) ?

What about $a=7$, $b=13$, $n=168$?

@YCor: what about it ?

I think the question is far too vague. For instance, $n$ being a prime power is a trivial sufficient criterion ...

I see. Sounds a bit like "what is a general criterion to conclude that a number $n$ is even?"
